# Using openpyxl to change the value of all cells in a column based on the value that currently occupies those cells

Tags: python, if-statement, openpyxl

I am completely new to openpyxl so, as you can imagine, I am having pretty hard times when I try to make use of it.

I have an Excel report that contains only one sheet (called Sheet1). I'd like to search all cells in one column (column H) for a specific string ("OK" and "QNS") and change that "OK" to "In Inventory" and "QNS" to "Exhausted".

I think my main confusion is exactly what to employ here. Is it a while loop combined with if/elif? Or do I need to iterate? Please help me understand how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: This should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71513215/openpyxl-find-and-replace-values/71519057#71519057

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got this to work, but can someone check to see if this makes sense?

```
wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/User1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/ March.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
conditionUpdate = {"OK": "In Inventory","Discrepancy: Subject": "In Inventory"}

for rowNum in range(2, ws.max_row):
    condition = ws.cell(row=rowNum, column=8).value
    if condition in conditionUpdate:
        ws.cell(row=rowNum, column=8).value = conditionUpdate[condition]
```

Comment: Why not use `for cell in ws["H"]:…`?

Comment: Mostly because I'm pretty new at Python and even newer at Openpyxl, so I didn't even know I could do that. It's much simpler. Thank you!

Comment: It **is** in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation is terribly overcomplicated for noobs, especially when joints like Stack Overflow are so full of such friendly helpers :-)

Comment: This is covered in https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells and isn't complicated; simpler in fact than many suggestions on SO.